# go-git: How to authenticate at remote server?

Tags: git, authentication, go, gitea, go-git

I'm using the go project [go-git](https://github.com/src-d/go-git) as a git-client and want to fetch from a private git-repository hosted via [gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/).

The appropiate function to do that is [`func (r *Remote) Fetch(o *FetchOptions) error`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4#Remote.Fetch), which expects an [`transport.AuthMethod`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing/transport#AuthMethod) object for authentication.

I tried the following:

```
repo, _ := git.PlainOpen("/path/to/project/folder")
err := repo.Fetch(&git.FetchOptions{
    Auth: http.NewBasicAuth("someUser", "andThePassword"),
})
```

...which simply returns:

> invalid auth method

The same happens if I use

```
authenticator, _ := ssh.NewSSHAgentAuth("git")
```

from the package `"gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing/transport/ssh"`.

And also if I use a certificate:

```
authenticator, _:= ssh.NewPublicKeysFromFile("gitea name", "/home/name/.ssh/id_rsa", "passphrase")
```

How do I find out which authentication method is supported, and are there existing implementations of `transport.AuthMethod` that I could use?

Comment: Your usage looks correct to me, maybe there is a bug? There was a recent issue [#618](https://github.com/src-d/go-git/issues/618) on the project that might indicate a useful workaround: `&git.CloneOptions{ URL: "https://user:pass@host/repo.git" }`

Comment: @orirawlings Such an url can only be applied when cloning a new repository. When I already have the repository local, I open it with `PlainOpen`, and then use `Fetch`, for which I cannot specify the url anymore. (The url is taken from the `.git/config` file. And even if I modify the url there, it returns "invalid auth method"

Comment: which kind of protocol are you using? HTTP or SSH? or maybe git?

Comment: @mcuadros I'm using http

Comment: can you print "git remote -v"?

Comment: @mcuadros Here you go (I replaced the actual url): `origin https://companyname.com/project/name (fetch)
origin https://companyname.com/project/name (push)
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here was, that I was using the wrong http-package to acquire the authenticator.

I used the `BasicAuth()` from the package `net/http` - however, the correct http package to use is `gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing/transport/http`.

When changing the import and using the (compatible) BasicAuth-authenticator from there, it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with `gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4`

```
func cloneGit() (err error) {
    username := "dude"
    password := "super-secret-Personal-access-token"
    repo := "github.build.company.com/org/repo-name.git"
    url := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s:%s@%s", username, password, repo)
    options := git.CloneOptions{
        URL:      url,
        Progress: os.Stdout,
    }
    r, err := git.PlainClone("./src", false, &options)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println(r.Log)
    return err
}
```